# How can you design a drug to modify apoptosis to treat a disease such as cancer?

Tags: cell-biology

How can you design a drug to modify apoptosis to treat a disease such as cancer? Im in highschool so can someone please explain in simple terms. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

The new cancer drugs are custom designed antibodies that have a cell-killing agent attached to them. These antibodies specifically attach to the cancer cells, and kill them. Other methods, like traditional chemotherapy target cells that are actively dividing, like hair in addition to cancer. Cancer cells are defined by uncontrolled cell division. But traditional chemotherapy, in simple terms, stresses the body to near death, differentially killing actively dividing cells. The new targeted methods are much less toxic.